# Windows Explorer: Customize view settings via batch or shell-extension?

Tags: windows, shell, windows-explorer, batch

In folders with shortcuts (and junctions) I oftenly like to have mid-sized icons, sorted names and grouping by type. Alas, Explorer oftenly forgets these settings once I made them manually.

The natural solution would be *desktop.ini*. AFAIK it isn't possible to define view settings in *desktop.ini*. [Command-line options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457) are also very limited.

Is there a *rundll32*-trick we can use from a batch file? Even better, a shell extension would be useful that refines the useless "Burn" button in the explorer accordingly.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: By "Manually", you are referring to setting through Normal GUI or through the Registry ?

Comment: Through the GUI. Where in the registry are the settings per folder stored? Maybe a simple batch-script could reset them for certain folders.

Answer (score 0):

You might have luck with getting the view settings you want to "stick" by making sure that the settings are applied under the property dialog.

1. First make the folder view as you would like it.
2. Under Windows 7 open the folder view properties but clicking
   **Organize** -> **Folder and Search Options** -> **View**
3. Click **Apply to Folders**.

Note this button might apply the same settings to more than one folder, it's not really clear.

[image]

Regarding the burn button you can disable this through the registry:

1. Type regedit in the run (search) box on the Start Menu and press
   Enter. It will open Registry Editor.
2. Navigate to the following key:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
3. In right-side pane create new DWORD called **NoCDBurning** and set its value
   to 1.
4. Close the registry editor and you should see the Burn button
   disappear from the explorer.

Comment: Thank you. Applying settings to all folders might be helpful for some users. AFAIK it's an old trick that already worked in 9x. But I want to have sticky and reproducable view settings per folder, not one setup for everything. Also, the Burn-button itself is not the problem for me (I just thought we could reuse it).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 there are five types of folders, probably when you changed the folder settings and "apply to folders", the aplication was only for the "general" type of view.

There is a large tutorial about how to configure the different types of view in [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/).

Answer (score 0):

i searched for the same thing and found a great solution. i am looking for other settings but im sure it might work for you if you find the right red entry:

You can set the option in the GUI and then export a regfile. You can then just click on this regfile anytime to set all options at a later time (or new PC).

go to explorer view settings and set it up the way you want.

In my case it was: show file extensions, explorer tree following the opened folders and compact view.

then open regedit and navigate to:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]

select that node with the mouse so its highlighted then in regiedit select File->Export.
a dialogue will ask for a filename (extension reg) and save it.

whenever you want to activate your settings just double click on the reg file and instantly all is set.

maybe your settings are one level up.

just remember to backup your reg file before trying things!